# How to make Final Cut Pro created DVD disc playable on DVD players?

Tags: final-cut-pro, dvd-burning

I am using Final Cut Pro on Mavericks and Yosemite.  Even though the one on Mavericks says: the latest version cannot run on the current OS -- must install the latest compatible version instead.  However, both versions on Mavericks and Yosemite report version 10.1.4.

And when I create a DVD disk using Share -> DVD and create a disc, burned by either the SuperDrive or a Pioneer drive, the disc cannot be played on a set top box DVD player... the disc I created using iDVD on an old Macook with Snow Leopard, can be played on that set top DVD player though.

Is there some way to make it work?

Comment: Normally the way you describe is the correct way to do it.  I did this in the recent past with FCP X 10.0.9 (the latest version on Mac OS X 10.8.5).  What you could try is to see if the proper DVD content is created by sharing it to your hard drive instead of directly to your DVD drive.  This will create a disk image, which you can burn later using Disk Utility or other compatible burning software.  Also burning it this way could be a workaround in case something does not work when directly burning from FCP X.

Comment: yes I did try that on the Macbook Pro... getting a `.img` file first and then using Disk Utility to burn it.  The result is the same: can't be played on a set top DVD box... I could use VLC to open the disc and it is like a DVD disc though